# How to compare non-nested SEMs with categorical outcome

Tags: categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I'm running several SEMs with a categorical outcome using the WLSMV-estimator in lavaan. My goals are to (1) compare a one- with a two-factor and a three-factor model and (2) also to compare two models with different indicator variables for the iv-factors. In general, the models look like this:

```r
sem_av12_iv1 ​<- '
#Model 1

AV1 ~ av1 + av2 + av3
AV2 ~ av4 + av5 + av6

IV1 ~ iv1 + iv2 + iv3

#Controlvariables

AGE   =~ age
age ~~ 0*age

SEX   =~ sex
sex   ~~ 0*sex

B_EDU =~ KM_Bild    ### Education
KM_Bild ~~ 0*KM_Bild

#Measurement error correlation 
                ​
AV1 ~~ AV2
                ​
# Paths

AV1 ~ IV1 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU
AV1 ~ IV1 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU'


sem1 <- sem(sem_av12_iv1 ,
            ​data=a,
            ​estimator     = "WLSMV",
            ​mimic         = "Mplus",
           ​ ​ordered = c("av1","av2","av3","av4","av5","av6"))

summary(sem1, fit.measures = TRUE, standardize  = TRUE, 
      rsquare = TRUE, estimates = TRUE, ci = FALSE)

sem_av12_iv23 ​<- '
#Model 2

AV1 ~ av1 + av2 + av3
AV2 ~ av4 + av5 + av6

IV2 ~ iv4 + iv5 + iv6    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors
IV3 ~ iv7 + iv8 + iv9    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors

#Controlvariables

AGE   =~ age
age ~~ 0*age

SEX   =~ sex
sex   ~~ 0*sex

B_EDU =~ KM_Bild    ### Education
KM_Bild ~~ 0*KM_Bild

#Measurement error correlation 
                ​
AV1 ~~ AV2
IV2 ~~ IV3

iv4 ~~ iv7
iv5 ~~ iv6
iv6 ~~ iv9
                ​
# Paths

AV1 ~ IV2 + IV3 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU
AV1 ~ IV2 + IV3 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU'


sem2 <- sem(sem_av12_iv23a ,
            ​data=a,
            ​estimator     = "WLSMV",
            ​mimic         = "Mplus",
           ​ ​ordered = c("av1","av2","av3","av4","av5","av6"))

summary(sem2,fit.measures = TRUE, standardize  = TRUE, 
      rsquare = TRUE, estimates = TRUE, ci = FALSE)

sem_av12_iv23a ​<- '
#Model 3

AV1 ~ av1 + av2 + av3
AV2 ~ av4 + av5 + av6

IV2 ~ iv4a + iv5a + iv6a    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors
IV3 ~ iv7a + iv8a + iv9a    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors

#Controlvariables

AGE   =~ age
age ~~ 0*age

SEX   =~ sex
sex   ~~ 0*sex

B_EDU =~ KM_Bild    ### Education
KM_Bild ~~ 0*KM_Bild

#Measurement error correlation 
                ​
AV1 ~~ AV2
IV2 ~~ IV3

iv4a ~~ iv7a
iv5a ~~ iv6a
iv6a ~~ iv9a
                ​
# Paths

AV1 ~ IV2 + IV3 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU
AV1 ~ IV2 + IV3 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU'


sem3 <- sem(sem_av12_iv23a ,
            ​data=a,
            ​estimator     = "WLSMV",
            ​mimic         = "Mplus",
           ​ ​ordered = c("av1","av2","av3","av4","av5","av6"))

summary(sem3,fit.measures = TRUE, standardize  = TRUE, 
      rsquare = TRUE, estimates = TRUE, ci  = FALSE)

sem_av12_iv234 ​<- '
#Model 3

AV1 ~ av1 + av2 + av3
AV2 ~ av4 + av5 + av6

IV2 ~ iv4 + iv5 + iv6    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors
IV3 ~ iv7 + iv8 + iv9    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors
IV4 ~ iv10 + iv11 + iv12    #### Variables IV2 and IV3 are IV1 split up in two factors

#Controlvariables

AGE   =~ age
age ~~ 0*age

SEX   =~ sex
sex   ~~ 0*sex

B_EDU =~ KM_Bild    ### Education
KM_Bild ~~ 0*KM_Bild

#Measurement error correlation 
                ​
AV1 ~~ AV2
IV2 ~~ IV3 + IV4
IV3 ~~ IV4

iv4 ~~ iv7 + iv10
iv7 ~~ iv10

iv5 ~~ iv6 + iv11
iv6 ~~ iv11

iv6 ~~ iv9 + iv12
iv9 ~~ iv12
                ​
# Paths

AV1 ~ IV2 + IV3 + IV4 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU
AV1 ~ IV2 + IV3 + IV4 + AGE + SEX + B_EDU



sem4 <- sem(sem_av12_iv234 ,
            ​data=a,
            ​estimator     = "WLSMV",
            ​mimic         = "Mplus",
           ​ ​ordered = c("av1","av2","av3","av4","av5","av6"))

summary(sem4,fit.measures = TRUE, standardize  = TRUE, 
     rsquare = TRUE, estimates = TRUE, ci  = FALSE)
```

Now there are a few critical things that I want to compare between models:

1. I want to compare model-fits between sem1 and sem2, where IV1 is the global construct and IV2 and IV3 (sem2) are the subdomains split up in two factors. The same goes for a model comparison between sem2 (or sem3) and sem4.
2. I want to compare sem2 and sem3 with regard to the different indicator variables (iv4/iv4a, iv5/iv5a...).

Here is, where I got stuck: regarding goal 1, I read that there is a package called *nonnest2* that will do the job, but only works with linear estimators like ML(R). So I wondered if there is another possibility do compare non-nested models (sem1 vs. sem2/3 vs. sem4) for categorical AVs.
Also, when I compared the models using the lavTestRT-function, I got the following two error messages for (a) comparison between sem2 and sem3 and (b) comparison between sem2 and sem2a:

Error in MASS::ginv(Delta1) %*% Delta0 : non-conformable arguments
In addition: Warning message:
In lavTestLRT(object = object, ..., model.names = NAMES) :
lavaan WARNING: some models are based on a different set of observed variables

AND

Warning messages:
1: In lavTestLRT(sem2a, sem2) :
lavaan WARNING: some models are based on a different set of observed variables
2: In lavTestLRT(sem2a, sem2) :
lavaan WARNING: some models have the same degrees of freedom

I would be really happy if anybody could point me into the right directions for troubleshooting.